# PATH not being changed for root user

Tags: user-account, path, root

I have added .bash_profile, .bashrc, .profile exeuctables in the /var/root dir.  However, unlike the normal users which execute their .bash_profile(s) and change the path.  There is no difference in the profiles but the root user one does not work.

I am unclear about how to get this workinkg.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: Generally, one doesn't use the root user in Mac OS X; the "Mac way" is to use sudo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the path in *~/.profile*

Answer (score 0):

To get to root I find it helpful to use:

```
sudo su -
```

This is a login shell, it runs root's dotfiles and sets up whatever environment you want root to have.

However, this will leave `$LOGNAME` as your logged in user.

To get a full login shell, as if you logged into the console as root:

login -fp root

Also, if you, like me, use root a lot, you can set that login command in your terminal.  In iTerm I have a root visor and window where I login as root.

Why?

- using sudo litters my homedir with root owned files. I trip over them,
- `sudo bash` or `sudo zsh` make me root but with my mortal environment. 
  This is not what I want. I want separation.
- Convenience. There are lots of things that root sees that admin users do not.

Chiggsy works in his homedir.

Root works on the system.

```
man login
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Mac OS X 10.7 or 10.8 you can create a `/etc/launchd.conf` file and add your variables as is :

```
setenv PATH /bin:/usr/bin:/Applications/Myapp.app/Contents/bin
```

and reboot

Answer (score -1):

For system wide changes (including root user) you have to edit `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bashrc`.